# seeing only half of the object when rotating opengl

Tags: opengl, rotation, geometry, orthographic

I'm trying to rotate a circle with OpenGL, but only half of the circle is shown when rotating. I guess there is something wrong in `init()`. Here is the code:

```
float angle = 0.0f;

void display(void)
{

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPushMatrix();
    //glTranslatef(x, y, 0);    // Move circle to desired location.
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    drawCircle(10.0, 50.0);

    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int val)
{
    angle += 0.5f;
    glutTimerFunc(val, timer, val);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void init()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-15.0, 15.0, -15.0, 15.0, 0.0, 200);
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ..
    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutTimerFunc(10, timer, 10);

    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the near plane is 0 in your orthographic projection, I assume, that on half of the circle is clipped by the near plane.

The projection matrix describes the mapping from 3D points of a scene, to 2D points of the viewport. It transforms from eye space to the clip space, and the coordinates in the clip space are transformed to the normalized device coordinates (NDC) by dividing with the `w` component of the clip coordinates. The NDC are in range (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1). Every geometry which is out of the NDC is clipped.
At Orthographic Projection the coordinates in the eye space are linearly mapped to normalized device coordinates.

[image]

This means, all the geometry which is in the cuboid, defined by `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`, `near` and `far`, is drawn on the viewport. If the geometry is not in between the near and the far plane it is not draw. You have to choose the near and far plan in that way, that all the geometry is in between. The values for `left`, `right`, `bottom`, `top`, `near` and `far` are set up by [`glOrtho`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml). Adapt your code like this:

```
glOrtho(-15.0, 15.0, -15.0, 15.0, -200.0, 200.0);
```